# How to create mysql table using php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i need to make application installation and need to make this tables in installation like wordpress. i have not error in php but this codes doesnt make any tables...

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'billboard');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    exit('Connection lost');
};
for($i=1;$i<=21;$i++){
    $table= "city".$i ;
    echo ($table . "<br>");
    $sql='CREATE TABLE $table
      ( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id),
        test0 VARCHAR(30),
        test1 VARCHAR(30),
        test2 VARCHAR(30))';
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo 'tables created';
    }
    else {
        echo 'Cant create tables';
    };
};
```

Comment: Nice syntax: `};` (nothing wrong but i can tell you that you're a js programmer)

Comment: You have to use double quotes `"` instead of single quotes `'`, otherwise variables aren't expanded.

Comment: You don't need many tables at all :) Put all cities data to one table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP evaluates variables in strings that are "wrapped with double quotes", but does not evaluate variables when strings are 'wrapped in single quotes'. In other words, single-quoted strings are literal.

In this case, you're attempting to create a table called $table 20 times. Instead, you can concatenate the variable into the loop like so:

```
$sql= 'CREATE TABLE ' . $table . '
    ( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id),
    //etc...
```

OR

```
$sql= "CREATE TABLE $table 
    ( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id),
    //etc...
```

I find it's more convenient to use double quotes for SQL queries anyway, since you will often need to put SQL values into single quotes (e.g. WHERE ID = '5').